# Google IMAP XOAuth only working for Authentication

Tags: java, oauth, gmail

I am trying to use XOAuth to populate a portlet with the most recent messages from the Google Apps Inbox.  However it seems to be fighting me every step of the way.  I'm using the 2-Legged code from:  [This Page](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tool-java-two-legged/).

I was having trouble authenticating but after backing my Javamail version down to 1.4 auth started working.  However now I get an **Invalid Credentials** error whenever I try to list folder contents or even *EXAMINE* a folder.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: enable SASL
DEBUG: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 198.133.178.17 o7if44308676igp.16
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! o7if44308676igp.16
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=user@cnm.edu, password=<non-null>
IMAP SASL DEBUG: Mechanisms: XOAUTH
IMAP SASL DEBUG: SASL client XOAUTH
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH
+ 
IMAP SASL DEBUG: challenge:  :
IMAP SASL DEBUG: response: GET https://mail.google.com/mail/b/user@cnm.edu/imap/?xoauth_requestor_id=user%40cnm.edu oauth_consumer_key="cnm.edu",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1335245518",oauth_nonce="4720724339258128",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="7HAU4923Gy7%2Ffqb3avk7Tg%2FXtVM%3D" :
R0VUIGh0dHBzOi8vbWFpbC5nb29nbGUuY29tL21haWwvYi9saG9sY29tYjJAY25tLmVkdS9pbWFwLz94b2F1dGhfcmVxdWVzdG9yX2lkPWxob2xjb21iMiU0MGNubS5lZHUgb2F1dGhfY29uc3VtZXJfa2V5PSJjbm0uZWR1IixvYXV0aF9zaWduYXR1cmVfbWV0aG9kPSJITUFDLVNIQTEiLG9hdXRoX3RpbWVzdGFtcD0iMTMzNTI0NTUxOCIsb2F1dGhfbm9uY2U9IjQ3MjA3MjQzMzkyNTgxMjgiLG9hdXRoX3ZlcnNpb249IjEuMCIsb2F1dGhfc2lnbmF0dXJlPSI3SEFVNDkyM0d5NyUyRmZxYjNhdms3VGclMkZYdFZNJTNEIg==
got folder: INBOX
DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A2 EXAMINE INBOX
A1 NO [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure)
A2 BAD Unknown command o7if44308676igp.16
A3 LOGOUT
* BYE Logout Requested o7if44308676igp.16
A3 OK Quoth the raven, nevermore... o7if44308676igp.16
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: A2 BAD Unknown command o7if44308676igp.16;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A2 BAD Unknown command o7if44308676igp.16
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:829)
    at TwoLegged.main(TwoLegged.java:37)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A2 BAD Unknown command o7if44308676igp.16
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:296)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.examine(IMAPProtocol.java:636)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:811)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm at a loss at this point.  The [Gmail OAuth Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol) don't indicate that any request other than Authentication needs to be signed but the **Invalid Credentials** error seems to imply otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a version of Java that didn't play well with versions of javamail newer than 1.4 which is what I needed.

I upgraded Java from 1.6.0_21 to 1.6.0_24.

Comment: Same issue with java version "1.7.0_10". Change the JRE to java version "1.6.0_24" and its working fine now !!